# Filtering based on "has any" to a column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[4,5,7,6]})
```

Expected output

```
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
```

I could achieve this using following way

```
>>> dfa[(dfa.a == 1) | (dfa.a == 2)]
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
```

But this is not really scalable since I want to do something similar to

```
??  dfa[(dfa.a has-any range(5,50))
```

Comment: I am not sure if understand - is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `np.arange` or `range`:

```
print (np.arange(5,51))
[ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50]

print (dfa[dfa.a.isin(np.arange(5,51))])
```

Or:

```
print (dfa[dfa.a.isin(range(5,51))])
```

Solution with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
print (dfa[dfa['a'].between(5, 50)])
```

Sample (one value is changed to `8`):

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,8],'b':[4,5,7,6]})
print (dfa)
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  7
3  8  6

print (dfa[dfa.a.isin(np.arange(5,51))])
   a  b
3  8  6

print (dfa[dfa.a.isin(range(5,51))])
   a  b
3  8  6

print (dfa[dfa['a'].between(5, 50)])
   a  b
3  8  6
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also do:

```
import pandas as pd
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[4,5,7,6]})
print dfa['a'].between(5, 50).any()
#False
print dfa['b'].between(5, 50).any()
#True
print ((5 <= dfa) & (dfa <= 50)).any()  # all columns together
#a    False
#b     True
#dtype: bool
```